# Issue formulating RegionPlot3D to visualize RegionIntersection

Tags: graphics3d, dynamic, geometry, regions

### **Description**

I am looking to visualize gas cloud growth within custom modules.

For demonstration purpose, it is assumed gas cloud takes a spherical shape whilst module is defined using a `Polygon`.

Among many other things, I struggle to extend `RegionIntersection` to include the entire `Polygon` as to visualize how gas cloud fills up the available volume.

Please see example below.

---

### **Example**

**Code**

```
DynamicModule[
 {radius = 1,
  region =  {{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 0}, {4, 5, 0}, {4, 8, 0}, {0, 8, 0}}, {{5, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 0, 0}}, {{5, 5, 0}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 0}}, {{4, 5, 0}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 8, 5}, {4, 8, 0}}, {{4, 8, 0}, {4, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}, {0, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 0}}, {{0, 0, 5}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 5}}}
 },

 Labeled[
 Panel @ Column[{
     (*Controls*)
     Manipulator[Dynamic @ radius, {1, 10, 1}],

     (*Visual*)
     Dynamic @ Show[{
        Graphics3D @ {Opacity @ 0.3, Polygon @ region},

        (*In RegionIntersection, I use Cuboid to demonstrate what I am after. I would like to replace it with whatever magic necessary to include the entire Polygon*)
        RegionPlot3D @ RegionIntersection[Ball[{2, 2, 2}, radius], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}]]
        },
       Boxed -> False,
       ImageSize -> Medium]
     },
    Alignment -> Center],
  Style["Example", 24], Top]
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: Example Output]

---

### **Objective**

Essently, I am looking to replace that `Cuboid[{0,0,0},{5,5,5}]` with something that would allow me to include the entire `Polygon`. Also, it would be great if solution would be flexible to take any 3D `Polygon` as a module.

---

### **Issues**

**I.1 [resolved]** - A level of confusion has been experienced when messing around with discretization. When deriving regions using spheres, the result differed from what has been initially expected. See code and output below:

**Code**

```
GraphicsRow @ {DiscretizeRegion @ 
   RegionDifference[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1]], 
  DiscretizeRegion @ 
   RegionUnion[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1]]}
```

**Output**

[image: RegionDifference with Sphere]

Whilst I was expecting output such as below.

**Code**

```
GraphicsRow @ {DiscretizeRegion @ 
   RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Ball[{1, 0, 0}, 1]], 
  DiscretizeRegion @ 
   RegionUnion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Ball[{1, 0, 0}, 1]]}
```

**Output**

[image: RegionDifference with Ball]

Although this issue has been resolved, I am not entirely sure why outputs with `Ball` and `Sphere` differ. I would be greatful if someone could expand on this matter or provide some reference to read about it.

Comment: Remember that `Ball[]` is a three dimensional solid, and `Sphere[]` is only the surface (by analogy with `Disk[]` and `Circle[]`).

Comment: @J.M thanks, the reason why I thought `Sphere[]` is treated as a solid is because it's noted here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SolidGeometry.html. That's probably the reason why I cannot get my `RegionIntersection[..]` to work

Answer (score 1):

### Description

This solution does not fully cover the requirements of the original post, but it does achieve the desired output. In order to visualize how arbitrary gas cloud fills up the available volume, I have combined two `Cuboid` regions using `RegionUnion`. This new region has then been tested for intersection with a `Ball` of varying radii using `RegionIntersection` to achieve the desired output. The issue with this solution is that it is not generic in a way it requires the `Polygon` to be subsidized with `RegionUnion` of `n` `Cuboid` shapes. At present, I am not sure how to automate this. Please see implementation below.

---

### Solution

This is a module as seen in OP

**Code**

```
region = {{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 0}, {4, 5, 0}, {4, 8, 0}, {0, 8, 0}}, {{5, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 0, 0}}, {{5, 5, 0}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 0}}, {{4, 5, 0}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 8, 5}, {4, 8, 0}}, {{4, 8, 0}, {4, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}, {0, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 0}}, {{0, 0, 5}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 5}}};

Labeled[
  Graphics3D[

  (*Graphics3D Specification*)
  {EdgeForm @ None, Opacity @ 0.5, Polygon @ region},

  (*Graphics3D Options*)
  Boxed -> False
  ],

  (*Label Specification*)
  Style["Module", 24],

  (*Label Options*)
  Top]
```

**Output**

[image: module example]

Then I combined two `Cuboid` entities using `RegionUnion` to achieve the desired region

**Code**

```
Show[RegionPlot3D @ RegionUnion[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}], Cuboid[{0, 5, 0}, {4, 8, 5}]], Boxed -> False]
```

**Output**

[image: region example]

Given the desired region has been derived, I subsidize it into the code presented in OP achieving the desired output

**Code**

```
DynamicModule[{
  radius = 1,
  region = {{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 0}, {4, 5, 0}, {4, 8, 
      0}, {0, 8, 0}}, {{5, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 
      0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 0, 0}}, {{5, 5, 
      0}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 0}}, {{4, 5, 0}, {4, 5, 5}, {4,
       8, 5}, {4, 8, 0}}, {{4, 8, 0}, {4, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 
      0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}, {0, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
      5}, {5, 0, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 8, 5}, {0, 8, 5}}}
  },
 Labeled[
  Panel@Column[{
     (*Controls*)
     Manipulator[Dynamic@radius, {1, 7, 1}],
     (*Visual*)
     Dynamic@Show[{
        (*Module*)
        Graphics3D@{Opacity@0.3, Polygon@region},

        (*Gas Cloud*)
        RegionPlot3D @ 
         RegionIntersection[Ball[{2, 2, 2}, radius], 
          RegionUnion[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}], 
           Cuboid[{0, 5, 0}, {4, 8, 5}]]]
        },
       (* Show Options*)
       Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Medium]},
    (* Column Options *)
    Alignment -> Center],
  (*Label Specification*)
  Style["Example", 24], Top]]
```

**Output**

[image: final output]

Comment: In principle you could use `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Polygon@region]` to convert the polygons to a region, but Mathematica seems unable to discretize the resulting RegionIntersection.